# StreamSets: How to unzip a folder using streamsets

Tags: apache-kafka, streamsets

I have a .zip file and I want to extract it using Streamsets and put data(.zip) to Kafka.

How can I do that?

Comment: What sort of data is in the zip file?

Comment: One single .csv file.

Comment: And .zip is in local

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For .zip files, configure the origin data format with **Compression Format** = `Archive`

Comment: No. Not helping

Comment: Can you edit your question with some details of the error you are seeing?

Comment: Thanks . I took help from this hint. It was helpful.

Comment: @metadaddy what if the zip is password protected ?

Comment: Hi @earl - I parted company with StreamSets in May 2020, and I no longer have access to the product. Sorry!